# Open existing class with button in another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with opening existing class from button which is in another class.
I don't have any idea how to make it working because I know I should in function add (Toplevel) but it's also not working.

```
class na_dane(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()

        # CODE ........

    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()

    # this code opens another window (class) which I have defined but not included here...
    def new_window(self):
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel.iconify(self.master)
        self.app = sinus(self.newWindow)

# here is the main class where when I click button it should open na_dane Class
class menu(na_dane):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        przycisk_Jednostkowo_Liniowa = tk.Button(
            text="Funkcja jednostkowo-liniowa",
            width=250,
            height=2,
            bg="blue",
            fg="yellow"
        ).pack()

        # HERE IS THE PROBLEM WHERE I TRY TO BIND BUTTON TO CLASS
        przycisk_Jednostkowo_Liniowa.bind("<Button>", lambda e: na_dane(master))
        przycisk_Jednostkowo_Liniowa.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("250x200")
    root.title("GRUPA 3")
    root['bg'] = '#FFFFFF'
    app = menu(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you attempt to pack `przycisk_Jednostkowo_Liniowa` in the same line as it is created. What this line of code is doing is creating a button with the characteristics described in your arguments, applying `.pack()` to it, then assigning the output of that `.pack()` execution to `przycisk_Jednostkowo_Liniowa`. Because `.pack()` doesn't have a return value, `przycisk_Jednostkowo_Liniowa` becomes `None`, so when you later attempt to bind a lambda to it, it doesn't recognize `.bind()` as a valid method. I tested the code with that `.pack()` removed and it worked for me.

Comment: I did it, it's giving no errors but the window won't load when I click on the button...

Comment: @OliwierPiasecki won't load in what way? It looks like na_dane() doesn't have any visible objects at the moment, so I tested it with a label and the label shows up. If you want it to open in its own window, it'll need its own tk.Tk() instance.